# How do I get my home page back

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, toolbar, homepage

A couple of days ago I had my niece help me install a new anti-virus, as I suck at this sort of thing. Somewhere along the line, it was asked if I wanted the *Ask-something* or other and yes was checked. Didn’t think much of it at the time but now instead of my usual home page—Google—, it says Ask.

How do I change it back to my original home page? It shows this whether I use Firefox or Internet Explorer

Comment: Are you talking about the start page in your browser? Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Yes the start page.

Comment: That will depend on your browser.

Comment: Okay not sure what to do with that. It says Ask.com weather I go in on Mozilla or Internet Explorer. Sorry I don't really know the lingo, I have one of these under protest and just when I get familiar with something they go and change it up on me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you'll want to do, both described on the Ask.com FAQ.

First, to [uninstall the toolbar](http://sp.ask.com/apn/toolbar/docs/default/faq/en/ie/index.html#na4), depending on your version of Windows you'll go: **Start Menu** > **Control Panel** > **Programs** or **Add or Remove Programs**; Select the Ask Toolbar then click on **Change** or **Remove** or **Uninstall**.

There are also instructions to [change your homepage back](http://sp.ask.com/apn/toolbar/docs/default/faq/en/ie/index.html#na24), but you can get those directly from [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/How%20to%20set%20the%20home%20page) or [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/internet-explorer/change-home-page).

Answer (score 1):

First uninstall toolbar.

Opera browser: First go to google.com.  Then click on Opera in the upper left hand corner, then go to settings, preferences, general, and click on use current.

Internet Explorer:  First go to google.com. Then click the gear icon in the upper right hand corner.  Then internet options, use current.

Firefox:  First go to google.com. Then click tools, options, make sure it says when firefox starts show my homepage and then use current page.

Chrome:  First go to google.com. Make sure you don't have any other tabs open otherwise it will include those too. Click on the 3 horizontal bars in the upper right hand corner.  Then setttings and go to where it says on start up choose Open a specific page or set of pages.  Click on Set pages.